# How to replace only the contents within brackets using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

How to replace only the contents within brackets using regular expressions?

```
String = "This is my string [123]"
```

I want to replace 123 with 456

```
Desired_String = "This is my string [456]"
```

My attempt:

```
regex = '.*\[(.*?)\].*'
re.sub(regex,'456',String)
>> 456
```

I'm not sure what regex to use so that it replaces the 123 with 456.

Comment: I'll ask the same question I always ask when brackets and regexps are mentioned together: what if your input string has nested brackets? What's the expected output for `"foo [bar [baz] qux] troz"`? If your regex logic is based on "match the first opening bracket, then the first closing bracket", you'll get `"foo [456] qux] troz"`

Comment: @Kevin True. In that case, the standard re module can't handle indefinite nesting, though the regex module's implementation would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you modify your regex and your replacement string a little, you get it:

```
regex = '\[.*?\]'
re.sub(regex,'[456]',String)
```

You don't need to match the entire string with `.*` for the substitution to work.

Also, it's not entirely required here, but it's good practice to raw your regex strings:

```
regex = r'\[.*?\]'
        ^
```

---

Another option would be to use negated classes, which will be faster as well!

```
regex = r'[^\[\]]+(?=\])'
re.sub(regex,'456',String)
```

It might be a little confusing, but `[^\[\]]+` matches any character except `[` and `]`.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xA2iL1)

Comment: @thefourtheye Then you have another problem, especially if it's `[abcd 123 def 123 ghi]`.

Comment: Actually I thought that the problem is complicated, but it is simple as you have shown. +1

Comment: One limitation I have with this is that the replacement string has to have brackets. Ideally, I'd want re.sub(regex,'456',String) to work just as well.

Comment: @Chris Ok, let me edit something little different in my answer then.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use look-ahead and look-behind assertions ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)):

```
>>> regex = r'(?<=\[).*?(?=\])'
>>> re.sub(regex, '456', 'This is my string [123]')
'This is my string [456]'
```